# How to write a URL that utilizes backslashes?

Tags: hyperref, windows, urls

I'm trying to link a directory from a server in my document, and because it's Windows notation, only backslashes are allowed: `\\server\path\to\dir`.

However using the `hyperref` package, I can't get this to work.

```
\href{run:\backslash\backslash server\backslash path\backslash to\backslash dir}{link}
```

results in odd escape characters, and

```
\href{run:\textbackslash\textbackslash server\textbackslash path\textbackslash to\textbackslash dir}{link}
```

results in a compilation error. Any help please?

**Edit**: Since this document is for internal use only, it's mainly a question of backslashes in URLs since this is the escape character.

Comment: Have you tried it with `/`?

Comment: Yes, `/` is not a valid notation for accessing the directory unfortunately.

Comment: Doesn't `\href{run:\\\\server\\path\\dir}{link}` work?

Comment: Oh I see, that does work. I thought `\\ ` was a way of introducing newlines, not the backslash escape.

Comment: not that it matters but that that _isn't_ a URL, URL always use `/` it's a local file path.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. I suppose it would be called a URI then?

Comment: A URI also uses forward slashes. It's a [UNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\\` to escape the backslash:

```
 \href{run:\\\\server\\path\\dir}{link}
```

Comment: Is there around having to use `\\`? It's tedious to have to copy URLs and manually add the additional backslash. Seems like a major shortcoming of the command.

Comment: @LloydChristmas Well it's possible can use v-type argument of xparse to define your own command `\myhref`, but if you do *just* that then it will not work inside argument of another command. Editor can replace \ with \\ easily enough.